# An analog switch controlled by digital logic

Tags: mosfet, switches, analog, 8051

I am trying to control the movement of a remote controlled car by using a 8051 microcontroller. In the remote controller circuit there are four push buttons(forward, backward, left, right). I need to replace these 4 push buttons with 4 switches that can be controlled by digital logic signal coming from my MCU. However, the input voltages to these switches are sinusodial waves whose frequencies are 40 MHz and amplitudes vary in 0-3V range. What should I use? I have thought of something like a tri state buffer but they work with digital inputs as far as I know. I think a MOSFET could do the job but I don't exacty know how it works. Any ideas?

Comment: Your description seems rather unlikely. Most likely the switches have either DC across them or are polled at a rate of maybe 1kHz- so you would see square (rectangular) waveforms. Make sure you have the ground connection on your oscilloscope probe connected to the circuit ground.

Comment: With only four buttons the chances are good that they simply connect a controller input pin to ground or battery negative. Inspection of the PCB or testing for continuity between the button pins and ground should answer this.

Comment: SN74HC4066D works from 2~6V for Vcc

Comment: Can you recommend me a thread to follow since I don't have a comprehensive knowledge on transistors, or any other easier and more suitable ways to perform this task?

Comment: what you say is remotely possible. .... did you choose the correct ground for your scope? .... can you post a picture of the waveform. .... also reduce the timebase of the scope to around 0.1mS/div just to see if there is an AM signal on the 40MHz carrier. ... post a picture if there is one

Comment: since you are replacing mechanical switches, using mechanical relays is one of the options.

Comment: I did not check if the signal was indeed a carrier, unfortunately I don't have the photo of the waveform rn but I can sure post it tomorrow. I have chosen the ground of the battery in the remote control as the ground of the probe.

Comment: Expanding on what @jsotola said, consider using reed relays.  You might be able to directly drive them with outputs from your microcontroller.  If not, a very simple NPN transistor circuit would suffice to interface the relay to the MCU.  The part linked here even has its own built-in flyback diode.
 https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/littelfuse-inc/HE3621A0510/HE207-ND/133258

Comment: i think that the reason that you are seeing the 40MHz signal at the switches, is because the circuit is very simple and the carrier oscillator is "polluting" the whole circuit and maybe you had your scope vertical sensitivity set to some low mV/div